# Excel VBA: More efficient way to pull in data from another workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

As a temporary fix before we transfer the process over to our CRM system, I've written a tool with Excel/VBA that allows the user(s) to do some territory planning.

This tool opens a workbook that's located on a shared directory.  It then pulls in data to the user's workbook on hidden sheets.  The user then makes their desired changes via sheets they can see (there's a save button on these sheets that changes the appropriate data on the hidden sheets).

When the user is done making all desired changes, they hit a 'confirm' button.  There is then a macro that reconnects to the workbook on the shared directory.  It pushes the data back to this workbook on the shared directory.  This workbook is [shared] so that more than one user can make changes concurrently, and the code is setup to prevent data from being overwritten inappropriately.

That said, I've come up with an annoying problem.  We have offices in many locations internationally.  It appears that the connection speed of users varies greatly.  Users that have slower connections are encountering the following error:

'Microsoft Office Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action.'

I suspect this is due to slower connections as microsoft's support site states that this error can come up when excel attempts to interact with another application which does not respond in a timely manner.

This error is coming up when the macro attempts to open the workbook in the shared directory, so connection speed is the main issue that makes sense.

I have discovered that I can block this error by using `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` but a better fix would be to make this process more efficient.

So my real question is, is there some more efficient method I can use to pull in that data, other than opening up the workbook?

Edit: Code where the worksheet opens the shared workbook:

```
Dim xlo As New Excel.Application
Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
Dim xlz As String, regions As String


xlz = Sheet1.Range("o1").Value & "\Region Planning\TestDB.xlsx"
Set xlw = xlo.Workbooks.Open(xlz)
```

Cell O1 contains the drive letter for the shared drive.

Comment: The efficiency of "pulling in data" from a shared Excel worksheet has almost entirely to do with the VBA code and rarely anything to do with the connection (anything that you can change, that is).  We cannot advise you on that code if you do not show it to us nor tell us anything about it.  On the other hand the blocking that you are experiencing seems like a likely consequence of trying to use an Excel spreadsheet as a shared database.  What works better is to use an actual database as a shared database (preferably a DBMS server).

Comment: I've edited the main post to include the code where the workbook attempts to access the shared workbook.  As stated in the main post, I believe this error is showing up prior to the macro actually attempting to write any data from the shared workbook to the destination workbook.  Unfortunately, (as this is a temporary fix) I'm not able to use a legitimate database for storing the central data.  The code opens the workbook in a new instance of excel as I do not want the shared workbook to be visible.

Comment: Generally RBarryYoung is 100% right, its a better approach to use a database for shared access to data than a much LIMITED shared workbook.... Anyways, are you opening it for read-only access? you can pass a parameter telling that you are opening to read-only for the `Open` method then this should avoid the error. Technically, you should open that workbook for read-only access then copy your data and close the object. People work at different speeds and you dont want to have the workbook opened all the time. let the used manipulate the copied data and reopen the workbook to update the data.

Comment: but keep in mind that the data pulled from a shared workbook is out-dated as soon as its pulled. you may be overwriting others people's work etc. I dont know how this whole sharing process 'works' at your place, but you should really reconsider transferring everything into a relational database

Comment: What you described is exactly how I have the workbook setup.  It gets opened, the data is pulled into the destination workbook (on hidden sheets) then the shared workbook is closed.  It's then reopened again before the user closes the workbook and the new data is pushed to the shared workbook.  Only data that has been changed by the user is pushed to the new workbook to prevent unintentional data overwrites.  I'm now guessing that the issue is due to the location of the server on which the shared directory resides and/or the users' connection speed.

Comment: I believe the server is located in the UK (as is my office) and no one in my office has any issue or delay when the workbook is pulling in the data.  The problem only comes up when being used remotely by users in remote countries such as Poland and Singapore.  I'd love to transfer this to a relational database, but as this was intended to be a temporary solution, I don't have that option :(

Comment: Is the data pretty well structured in the shared workbook? Maybe if you used ADO to read in "tables" it would come across the connection faster. I don't have a slow connection to test it, but let me know if you'd like an example.

Comment: Again, please show us the data that is reading/writng the shared worksheet.  The code that opens/connects to the spreadsheet is not helpful and is probably not where the problem is (and if it is, it probably cannot be fixed in the code).

Comment: Possibly relevant - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2807742 - depending if you use custom views and if any of your offices access the file via WiFi